# Microsoft SharePoint is not supported in 32-bit process. Please verify that you are running in a 64-bit executable

Tags: sharepoint, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I'm writing a console app for SharePoint 2013 on a 64-bit machine. I get this error when I try to execute the program:

"Microsoft SharePoint is not supported in 32-bit process. Please verify that you are running in a 64-bit executable."

Please let me know if you've had this problem in the past and can help. Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you checked the the properties for your project? (solution explorer, right click on the project, click on properties)
On the build tab check for that you select "Any CPU".

Comment: I actually had to uncheck "prefer 32-bit", but your answer helped me to locate the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Same.  For me it was changing Any CPU to x64.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

In Visual Studio: TOOLS>OPTIONS>Projects and Solutions>WEB PROJECT and Use the 64 bit versions of IIS Express for web sites and projects

Comment: Worked for me with SharePoint 2013 and a WCF application.

Answer (score 8):

I hit this problem while running a Unit Test (well, an integration test in "Unit Test" clothing). Changing the target for the unit test project just made the tests disappear from the Test Explorer. It is possible to run your tests (at least in VS2013+) as an x64 environment.

In Visual Studio, choose `Test > Test Settings > Default Processor Architecture > x64`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782531(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: Problem and solution confirmed with Visual Studio 2015 and SharePoint 2013. Unit test projects and SharePoint-related class library projects don't have the IIS-related options mentioned in other answers

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, if "Prefer 32-bit" is greyed out, and your Platform Target is already "Any CPU", the problem is that IIS Express is not 32 bit.

The solution is to change the solution's web server to Local IIS.

This blog details the steps in more detail:
[Platform Not supported Exception when running Visual Studio Web Application](http://blogs.msmvps.com/marafa/2013/12/16/platform-not-supported-exception-when-running-visual-studio-web-application/)

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue. The Build tab has the option `Any CPU`, but still it was not working.

I have selected explicitly `x64` as the **Platform target**, and the application works fine :)

Comment: This answer helped me 2 times!  I am building a custom `SPClaimProvider` and my unit test project was giving the 32-bit error.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was changing a registry key:

```
HCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\WebProjects\Use64BitIISExpress
```

to `1`, as shown here:

https://rule30.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/microsoft-sharepoint-is-not-supported-in-32-bit-process-please-verify-that-you-are-running-in-a-64-bit-executable/

Answer (score 0):

for me it was because of invalid reference to Microsoft.Shareppoint.dllafter migrating to SharePoint 2013 in a console application we used for some automation

just add below address of Microsoft.Shareppoint.dll

**Correct**

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll
```

you can found this reference to this correct dll , after creating a empty SharePoint 2013 project in your UAT.

I was getting this error inside my Windows 2012 R2 UAT and Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 , when my reference was incorrectly to a dll found in GAC

**Incorrect**

```
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll
```